# Automaticly replace a link with other "new link"

Tags: links

I want "a link" in my content "automaticly" replace with "new link"

Heres the explanation, in my all post content I want a link of `www.lol.com/?http:/rapidshare.com` automaticly replace with new link `http://rapidshare.com`

Whats the code to add in my functions.php ?? or any plugin that automaticly replace that old link with new one?

Answer (score 1):

This is the SQL:

```
UPDATE <YOUR_PREFIX_HERE>_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'www.lol.com/?http://rapidshare.com', 'http://rapidshare.com');
```

Either inject it directly into the database (via PHPmyAdmin and the like) or use WordPress to do so.

Here's the WordPress way:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "UPDATE <YOUR_PREFIX_HERE>_posts
        SET post_content = replace(post_content, %s, %s)",
        'www.lol.com/?http://rapidshare.com',
        'http://rapidshare.com'
        )
);
```

**// EDIT**
For completeness (as @birgire suggested): if you don't know the table prefix, you can let WordPress look that up:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts}
        SET post_content = replace(post_content, %s, %s)",
        'www.lol.com/?http://rapidshare.com',
        'http://rapidshare.com'
        )
);
```

Comment: Do I have to fill up UPDATE <YOUR_PREFIX_HERE>? and what is it?

Comment: I put the sql query but I've got this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<YOUR_PREFIX_HERE>_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'www.lol.com/?' at line 1

Comment: You just have to set `<YOUR_PREFIX_HERE>` to your WP table prefix. Normally, this is `wp`, however, you may have changed that to something else. You can see this either in your database (all WP tables have the same prefix), or in your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: You can use  `"UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET post_content = ..." ` or `"UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}posts SET post_content = ..." `.

Comment: @birgire Of course, that's right. I'll add that to my answer. I just thought, you'd normally know your table prefix (or if not, you most likely did not change it, so it's `wp_`), and thus `wp_posts` is slightly faster than `{$wpdb->posts}`. ;)

Comment: @user31445 If your question has been solved, please accept the particular answer (by clicking the check mark below the vote count) to let others know it has been solved, as well as to prevent your (seemingly unsolved) question from being pulled by the community bot.

Comment: Do I have to put function name on the top of global $wpdb; ? and what is the name for the function? any name? and also this new function going to wp-includes/functions.php right?

Comment: Btw I don't want to use database way but I want to use wordpress way

Comment: What? I thought, you had already done what you wanted!? [Your comment](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95695/automaticly-replace-a-link-with-other-new-link/95696?noredirect=1#comment130282_95696) made me think this. No, you do **not** have to put it in a function, and you especially do **not** have to put it in `wp-includes/functions.php`, but in the **`functions.php` file in your theme's directory**. Please **[edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/95695/edit)** and explain what you want to do now, why you want to do this (again?) and what your problem is.